# Regular Expression for Google Drive Api q objects

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to use the Google Drive API  to Search all file with Regular Expression . How can this be done in a single query? I have tried:

```
    files = drive.files().list().setQ("[a-d1-7]").execute();
```

And

```
  files = drive.files().list().setQ("fullText contains '[a-d1-7]'").execute();
```

But this request failed to yield the correct result.

Comment: regex isn't supported. See https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters